# Do Greek students use Greek letters to denote angles?

Tags: notation

In western schools is a tradition to use Greek letters to denote angles. I wonder what about Greek schools do they also use Greek letters to denote angles or do they prefer other kind of alphabet to avoid confusion?

Comment: Silly follow up question: which letters do they use for x and y?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold I live in Israel and the students use x and y, even though they have a totally different alphabet.

Comment: please do not double-post
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634929/do-greek-students-use-greek-letters-to-denote-angles

Comment: Another silly follow up question: how math expressions are written in cultures with right-to-left writing?

Answer (score 2):

An answer to both question and first comment:

Usually, numbers or the letters phi, omega are selected to denote angles, while x and y are the standard symbols for independent and dependent variables in functions.

See for example the 10th grade (15 years old) geometry book: http://ebooks.edu.gr/ebooks/v/pdf/8547/2608/22-0236-01_Eukleideia-Geometria_A-Lykeiou_Vivlio-Mathiti/ Theorem 1 at page 26,

and

The Algebra book of the same grade at http://ebooks.edu.gr/ebooks/v/pdf/8547/2466/22-0270-01_Algebra-kai-Stoicheia-Pithanotiton_A-Lykeiou_Vivlio-Mathiti/ Definition at page 146.